# SELECT INTO in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a MSSQL user and now I am converting my database to MySQL. I am writing the following query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * INTO new_tbl FROM tbl;
```

And I get the following error

```
Error : Undeclared variable new_tbl
```

How such a query should be properly written in MySQL?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use the CREATE TABLE SELECT syntax.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

Comment: SELECT INTO command creates new table and can be copied  data from one database to another as

Comment: Correct syntax is: CREATE TABLE new_tbl AS SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;

Comment: CREATE ... SELECT works, this should be the accepted answer. The "AS" keyword is apparently optional, and SELECT INTO doesn't work with MySQL.

Comment: Emphasis that it does not create indexes!

Answer (score 103):

In MySQL, It should be like this

```
INSERT INTO this_table_archive (col1, col2, ..., coln)
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM this_table
WHERE entry_date < '2011-01-01 00:00:00';
```

[MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

Comment: Subtle difference. In this case the table has to exist. For `select into`, it doesn't. In fact, I think it's an error if it does. So this solution should be prefaced with statements that duplicate the table schema.

Comment: As paxdiablo says, this requires the table you are inserting into to already exist.  The MSSQL syntax that OP is used to creates the table for you.

Comment: May not have answered the OP's question but fortunately this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: THIS CAN BE A BAD THING!!!!  To me this is not a good answer because the standard Insert / Select locks the tables you are selecting and joining on.  If you have several thousand records this will freeze all those tables.    The select into tables does not lock the tables being selected and joined on.