# SELECT * INTO <non existent table>- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to move a select statement's result into a new non-existent table but not able to figure how.

In MS SQL, I would be following the below,

```
SELECT * INTO <NON_EXISTING_TABLE> FROM
(
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 A 
JOIN TABLE2 B
ON A.DescriptionNo = B.DescriptionNo 
WHERE A.DescriptionNo =1) A
```

When i quickly looked it up , I can see only answers to insert data into an existing table but not dynamically create a new table with the result of the statement.

Please advice !

Comment: I guess you are looking for [Create a temporary table in a SELECT statement without a separate CREATE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809393/select-into-in-mysql

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The answer was right there and I had missed it. Thanks for your responses though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution showed above works perfect also for selected rows. For example I am creating demonstration rows for my nice2work project, and this works perfect.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=500;
UPDATE tmptable SET id = 0;
UPDATE some fields I need to change
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM tmptable;
DROP TABLE tmptable;

//  You can use this same also directly into your code like (PHP Style)
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptable SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=500;
UPDATE tmptable SET id = 0;
UPDATE some fields I need to change
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT * FROM tmptable;DROP TABLE tmptable;";
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to create a new table from a select, you can use this syntax:

```
create table new_table as
select *
from existing_table
where ...
```

Comment: Don't know who down voted this but according to dupe question it is the right solution